# How to set utf8mb4 on MySQL 5.7 (windows)

Tags: mysql, windows, character-encoding

I have an installation of MySQL 5.7 on a Windows 7 machine.
I need to change the character set of the database in order to persist emoji.

The configuration into my.ini:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Into the windows services I saw that the configuration file path that is loaded is correct.

Looking into database properties with the query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

I got the following results:

```
Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server    utf8_general_ci
```

So, the values of collation_server, character_set_system, character_set_server, character_set_results, character_set_connection, character_set_client are wrong.

How can I fix them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After connecting to MySQL, perform `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.  That will establish that your client is using the full 4-byte encoding for reading/writing.

You can do this in my.cnf/my.ini:

```
init_connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

but keep in mind that when connecting as root (or any `SUPER` user), `init_connect` is ignored.

Also, the tables/columns must be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.